# What values are legal for the transaction's version field?

Tags: transactions, transaction-version

In the transaction's version field, what values are legal?

What values have actually been seen in the blockchain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In the transaction's version field, what values are legal?

The version field is a 32 bit unsigned integer, any value is valid. Version 0, or version numbers above the nodes `CURRENT_VERSION` constant [are considered non-standard and are not relayed](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/b94ae81576c199c9a44453b8c9b17e8303f67b72/src/policy/policy.cpp#L61-L64), though they can appear in blocks.

> What values have actually been seen in the blockchain?

`1` is the only number to have been in use at this point in time. [BIP62](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0062.mediawiki) proposes bumping the version to `3` (skipping `2` entirely) to match the block version and avoid confusion, however this was withdrawn. BIP68 specifies that transactions spending a CSV output must have version `2` or higher.